# How to find roll back of a Java EE Container-Managed Transactions

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions

I am using Java EE Container-Managed Transactions in my code. I am using the annotation `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` for one of my methods. This method is supposed to update values in a database object. But this method sometimes fails and the transaction is rolled back by the container.

Is there any way to quickly find whether the transaction is rolled back or not by the container? I know we can query again in the database to really check and understand the value have been changed or not, but I don't want to query again. I was wondering if I could understand whether that transaction has been rolled back or not, I could inform the client with a FAILURE message.

Any advice on this topic is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that always rolls back a transaction is an exception (provided it is not an '@ApplicationException(rollback=false)'. On the client side, you can catch this exception, and you will be guaranteed (as per spec) that the transaction was rolled back.

```
@Remote //or @Local
public interface MyBeanInterface {

 void doSomeTransaction();
}

public class MyController {

  @EJB
  private MyBeanInterface bean;

  public void doSomething() {
   try {
      bean.doSomeTransaction();
   }catch(EJBException ex){
     //the exception is always wrapped in an EJBException, unless it is an @ApplicationException
     //do something with the exception
   }
  }
}
```